# Why ArrayList.this.modCount is different from this.modCount

Tags: java, arraylist

In the source codes of ArrayList,I found some puzzled codes following:

```
public int size() {
        if (ArrayList.this.modCount != this.modCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        return this.size;
}
```

The modCount is inherited from  **AbstractList**.I can't find another modCount.So I think the **ArrayList.this.modCount** is the same as the **this.modCount**.But actually,**ArrayList.this.modCount != this.modCount** can be true!

Why don't the same variable  equal to itself?

=====================================================================

The code is in the `SubList` class.It's my mistake.

Comment: `ArrayList.this` refers to the `this` pointer of `ArrayList`, while `this` refers to the nearest class (not parent classes). I'm guessing they both have a `modCount` member field so you need to access it via `ArrayList.this`.

Comment: Where did you find the code of `size()`?

Comment: Could you show us where you find that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see that code in any `size()` method within `ArrayList`, but I see that condition in `ArrayList.SubList`'s `checkForComodification()`.

The condition compares the `modCount` member of two different instances - one is an `ArrayList.SubList` instance, and the other is the enclosing `ArrayList` instance (that the instance `ArrayList.this` is referring to).

`SubList` is an inner class of `ArrayList`, and therefore each instance of `SubList` has a corresponding instance if `ArrayList` which is called the enclosing instance.

Both `ArrayList` and `ArrayList.SubList` are direct sub-classes of `AbstractList`, so both inherit the `modCount` member from that class, but the code in question compares the `modCount` member of two different instances.

Comment: It's my fault.I find it in the nested class `SubList` of `ArrayList`.Thank you for reminding.